# android application not able to run on phone

Tags: android, debugging

Please help me, I want to debug my application into micromax ninja phone. i have provided all the settings i.e debug mode on in phone and as well as in my android manifest file also but my problem is i can't find my cell connected.
[image]

what i am missing?( i have also provided the run configuration as manual)
[image]
please help me by giving this answer.

i have cell phone version 4.0.4 and making application in 2.1

Comment: maybe you need install some drivers? what kind of phone you have?

Comment: depends on the device, what phone do you have?

Comment: micro max ninja model no A89

Comment: http://www.droidiser.com/2012/11/how-to-install-drivers-for-any-android.html

Comment: if the minSdkVersion="7" or 8 then no way the device will appear 
try to tun it using another application with minSdkVersion="14" and above , and you will see it , also you need the drivers for the device

Answer (score 0):

install the device specific drivers

install google usb drivers from sdk manager

If still your phone is not detected then

from command prompt move to yousdkfolder \sdk\platform-tools

and type

adb kill-server

and then

adb start-server